# Error on loading WePay Embedded Checkout IFrame in Windows

Tags: javascript, cakephp, iframe

I am attempting to set up the WePay API to accept payments on my website via the Embedded Checkout,and I am running into some issues.The website is currently hosted on my local machine for testing and was created in Cakephp.when i am executing it in browser(Google Chrome,firefox) using linux OS.The IFrame is loaded many times correctly,but if i try to execute it in Windows OS browser(Firefox, Google Chrome) the wepay IFrame checkout is loaded only 2 times,after that it does'nt load the IFrame.

Inside Controller:

```
Wepay::useStaging($client_id, $client_secret);

$wepay = new WePay($access_token);

try {
    $checkout= $wepay->request('/checkout/create', array(
        'account_id' => $account_id, 
        'amount' => $amount,
        'short_description' => "this is a test payment",
        'type' => "donation",
        'redirect_uri'=> LIVE_SITE.'/users/thanks/'.$aid.'/'.$lid,
        'mode' => "iframe"

        )
    );
}
catch (WePayException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

$this->set('checkoutnews',$checkout);
```

Under View File:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stage.wepay.com/js/iframe.wepay.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        WePay.iframe_checkout("checkout_div", "<?php echo $checkoutnews->checkout_uri ?>");
        </script>
```

Comment: Are there any console messages?

Comment: is there showing any error message?

Answer (score 3):

replace :

```
'mode' => 'iframe'
```

with

```
'hosted_checkout' => ['mode' => 'iframe']
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work when u add the following

'mode' => "iframe"

Remove that and you should be fine.